# Separable equations and implicit differentiation and differential form.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm a tad confused about some of the symbolic notation in my book regarding separable equations:

[image]

I thought when you integrate an equation (let's call it a) and differentiate it, you wind up with a again. I'm a bit confused why we're using chain rule in the last line. where did the last $\frac{dy}{dx}$ come from?

also how do we know y is a function of x? Why isn't x a function of y?

I guess the key step is that we're differentiating with respect to x?

Conceptually, what does it mean to write something in "differential form"?

Comment: The expression $h(y)\,\mathrm{d}y=g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ can be given a mathematically exact meaning in the theory of [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form), but that would require introducing a lot of definitions and auxiliary results, little relevant to the ODE in question. So, for starters, it is (considered) better to look on it as purely formal calculations.

Comment: If you put $H(y)$ to be a (fixed) antiderivative of $h(y)$ and $G(x)$ to be a fixed antiderivative of $g(x)$, then $H(y)-G(x)=C$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant, gives a family of solutions of the original separable ODE. **Sometimes** (perhaps for some values of $C$), the equation $H(y)-G(x)=C$ can be solved as a function with independent variable $x$ and dependent variable $y$, and **sometimes** the other way (and sometimes in both ways).